# How to maintain tags for products in Moqui

Tags: moqui

Tags are popular keywords for product identification. They can be used for filtering/sorting the products by certain features.
For eg. I have a product **Blue t-shirt** in my catalog with tags (Polyester, round, fitness etc)

I need to maintain tags. How can we do it in Moqui? Which entity is suitable for this.

Comment: ProductFeature: https://moqui.org/m/docs/mantle/Mantle+Structure+and+UDM/Product#definition---feature-mantleproductfeature

Comment: Thank you @DavidE.Jones